# Issue with Safe Indexation on Arianee Supernet: Stuck at "Indexation" Stage

Tags: blockchain, polygon, evm

**Background:**
This issue is a continuation of the discussion from Issue #124.

**Problem:**
I am encountering an issue with the indexation process of Safe on the Arianee Supernet. Despite following the deployment and setup procedures, the creation of a Safe gets stuck at the "Indexation" stage. Below is a detailed account of the steps I've taken and the observations made.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Deployed "Safe Frontend" by cloning the repository and forcing the resolution of @safe-global dependencies to the correct versions containing Safe deployment information on Arianee Supernet (@safe-global/**/@safe-global/safe-deployments: 1.28.0).

The Safe Frontend launches correctly.

Configured and launched "Safe Infrastructure" with Docker Compose, stopping the "Safe Frontend" container as it's already running in standalone mode.

Configured Arianee Supernet in the Django administration interface.

The Arianee Supernet is detected by all "Safe Infrastructure" services with no anomalies in logs.

Arianee Supernet appears correctly on the Safe Frontend. Safe creation is possible, but indexing does not complete.

I've checked that contracts are present at the deployment locations on Arianee Supernet.

I've verified that the contracts deployed on Arianee Supernet match those deployed by Gnosis Safe on Ethereum.

Investigated the RPC method types supported by Supernet. traces_ methods are not supported, while eth_ methods, including eth_getLogs, are supported. Concluded that we definitely need to configure the Arianee Supernet in L2 mode.

Deployed the Safe Infrastructure in L2 mode to enable the indexer to make RPC calls using eth_getLogs.

Reinstalled Safe Infrastructure ensuring L2 mode was active, and selected L2 when adding the chain via the Django admin interface.

Attempted to create a new Safe, but the process remained stuck on "Indexation".

Also configured webhooks for cache clearing and also tried disabling the cache entirely to rule out cache-related issues.

Current Situation:
So the creation of a Safe remains stuck on the "Indexation" step, with the indexer seemingly not detecting events, despite transactions for creating a Proxy for a Safe executing correctly on-chain.

Request for Help:
Any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. If there are further details or logs that could assist in troubleshooting, please let me know.

**Additional Note:**
Furthermore, Arianee is willing to pay for support if necessary to resolve this issue. We are committed to finding a solution and are open to any available support options.

Thanks a lot!